# ExtJs form issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have developed a form

```
Ext.define('package.formname',{
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
    closeAction : 'hide',
    layout : 'fit',
    resizable : true,
    modal : true,
    defaultFocus: 'id',
    items : item_name
 });

 var item_name = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
                    some vbox and hbox layouts combines.
                 });
```

So, now this form gets activated when a button is clicked. I have configured in the controller part. No issues. After filling the form, the values are passed to the controller and the responsible store gets hit and JSON data is transferred to a Web application to insert this record.

When I again click on the button which opens this form, it has all the fileds popullated with the old values. I am doing a refresh every time to poppulate the form and submit it. How to avoid this?

Any thoughts?

Comment: You mentioned using a controller so I assume you are using MVC.  Why are you not just creating a class for your form and including it in your window items config?

Comment: I did the same thing, created the form inside the var item_name and included this in items config of the window portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're creating an instance of the form, so the reference to the form object is always the same. Instead, you should pass the form when you create the window:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = new Ext.form.Panel();
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show data of a model record, you can use

[Ext.form.Panel.loadRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord)